# Map attribute in Datanucleus JDO

Tags: java, maven, jdo, datanucleus

I have class which has Map, but when I try to presist this entity, throws null pointer exception. What could be wrong in my code/settings?

My class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class MyClassEntity implements MyClass {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.NATIVE)
    private String id;

    @Persistent @Join @Element(embedded="true")
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "implementation-classes", value = "com.company.MySecondClassEntity")
    private Map<String, MySecondClass> map = new HashMap<String, MySecondClass>();

    // Getters and setters here

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.AbstractStatementGenerator.<init>(AbstractStatementGenerator.java:101)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.AbstractStatementGenerator.<init>(AbstractStatementGenerator.java:139)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.UnionStatementGenerator.<init>(UnionStatementGenerator.java:153)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.RDBMSJoinMapStore.getSQLStatementForGet(RDBMSJoinMapStore.java:770)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.RDBMSJoinMapStore.getValue(RDBMSJoinMapStore.java:639)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.RDBMSJoinMapStore.putAll(RDBMSJoinMapStore.java:195)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.MapMapping.postInsert(MapMapping.java:135)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.InsertRequest.execute(InsertRequest.java:520)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertTable(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:166)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:142)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2377)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2353)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1593)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
    at com.mycompany.dao.impl.JDOGenericDao.save(JDOGenericDao.java:63)
    at com.mycompany.dao.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Maven dependecies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>[1.2, 1.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have thought that "value-implementation-classes" as an extension key makes way more sense than what you have there (otherwise how is it to know that you are talking about the values of the map and not the keys?)

Comment: I tired with value-implementation-classes, but it threw same exception still.

Comment: And what does the log say? perhaps, just perhaps there is some key bit of information in there ;-)

Comment: I get same exception as earlier and datanucleus.log file has no errors or warnings. I have used datanucelus example project as template. How could I debug this problem?

Comment: A WARNING message is output when using a join table "Collection has been specified with a value-type {...} which is an interface. DataNucleus doesnt currently fully support the use of value-types that are interfaces. Please change the value-type to be a class.". Obviously the log also goes down to DEBUG level and just looking for warnings/errors isn't going to help you in the long run for debugging either